# Netlify frontend with Heroku backend, proxy API calls from backend

Tags: vue.js, heroku, frontend, backend, netlify

i have a git repo with server and client in the same repository, i deployed a subtree of the server to Heroku and a the whole repo to Netlify, with the help of `netlify.toml` i wanted to build only the front-end (the client folder) so i did this:

```
    [build]
    base = "client"
```

Now, my vuejs routing had problems so i had to create a new `_redirects` into my dist folder ( the build folder ) specifying the routing, having the route mode set to 'history' , i wanted a clean URL.

Now, the problem that i have encountered is how can i proxy all the API calls i have on my heroku backend app to netlify ?
The heroku APIs are called at the `https://myherokuapp.herokuapp.com/api`

I've tried setting some redirects into the _redirect file:

```
/*    /index.html   200

/api/*  https://myherokuapp.herokuapp.com/api/:splat  200
```

But the answer of that API call is always page not found.

Is there maybe a problem with `/*    /index.html   200` that makes my api calls response 404 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried changing the order:

```
/api/*  https://myherokuapp.herokuapp.com/api/:splat  200

/*    /index.html   200
```

Comment: There is an order in the execution of the redirects, so makes sense. Glad it worked.